# How can I take something in then out in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have been looking for a way to pull something out of my main method into a outer method then plop the output of the outer method back into the main method (this is in Eclipse).

I have been looking for a strangely long time for a answer for this but everything seems way more advanced than what I am looking for. If anyone can help it would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `extract method` refactoring. Select the code block that you want move into a different method and press Shift-Ctrl-M. Or is it Ctrl-Alt-M? Can't remember right now.

And here I go giving refactorings to someone that doesn't even know what a method is....